# How to host audio units in osx

Tags: macos, core-audio

I've been looking through the audio unit documentation for OSX, and I haven't found any good resources about how to host an audio unit in OSx. There are lots of resources for how to build audio units, and some about hosting in IOS. Has anyone seen a good document to this effect?

Thanks

Comment: This might help https://github.com/johndpope/pyau

Answer (score 0):

i'm not sure how the samples have changed over the years... it looks like the current related samples don't address the issue in depth.

in the past, there were a few very basic examples which shipped with the DevTools distributions. iirc, these were distributed in the `DEVTOOLS/Examples/` or `DEVTOOLS/Extras/`.

the AU APIs haven't changed a whole lot since they were written (fast dispatch was added along the way...), so the samples should help with the backend. they were written in the era when Cocoa UIs were still very new to AUs, so the frontend will be the aspect that's changed the most.

you may want to look for them in your Xcode 3.0 or Xcode 2.5 installs.

Comment: Thanks. I've found those - unfortunately, most of them don't compile. As you said, the APIs haven't changed much, but aparrently the project structure has.

Comment: yeah - the contents of the CA Public sources have shifted quite a bit over the years. you can either fix the references, rebuild, or read the relevant bits. it's better than nothing...

Answer (score 0):

This [1] doc shows how to open audio units from within an OSX app. It doesn't cover the general case of hosting audio units though.

[1] http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/technotes/tn2091/_index.html